# Should I delete data before deleting its partition and extending over?

Tags: partitioning, automation, powershell, diskpart

I have multiple computers with the main drive split into C and D partition. D just has random data, C has the OS. I plan on copying over data from D to C then deleting D and extending C over it. Can I just delete the partition and extend? Or should I wipe all data before deleting the partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just deleting the D: partition and extending C: will be fine. 
One the partition is gone, the hard drive won't care what was there before.

The data to say where files are stored (journal in the case of NTFS) is stored in the partition itself, so when you delete the partition, the computer doesn't know anything about the files that were on the partition before, and thinks it's just free space ready to be used again.

When you then create the new partition, the computer will assume it's all free as the journal will be empty. Despite the fact that there is data already there, the computer will go ahead and write new data ontop of the old data when you store files in the extended C: partition.

Comment: I agree with what Lawrence has written; however, I want to point out that if you wanted to delete data for security reasons (say, if you were selling the disk and didn't want sensitive data to fall into the wrong hands), deleting the partition is insufficient. In that case, you'd want to use a tool like [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) or Linux's `dd` command to completely erase the disk. In your case, there's no obvious reason to use such a tool; I just want to mention it in case somebody else who does have such a need reads this.

Comment: Thanks - I just wanted to be sure.  As far as security, once the merge is complete, the entire disk will be encrypted.  Also since I'm doing this across many machine (all of which are windows based) I wanted a shortest time possible option, hence why data is being migrated rather than moved to a network drive and then restored later.